# Does the android logger run on the main thread?

Tags: android, performance, logging

Does the Android logger run on the main thread? If so, does logging big entries have a performance impact on rendering the UI?

Comment: Too much string concatenation will affect the performance.

Comment: just take a look at the log class and make your hands dirty: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Log.java

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is it depends on where you are calling **Log** from so yes, it also runs on the main thread. You are allowed to put log anywhere you want.

Since it's printing log into your console it has definitely impacted on your app performance

Here is an example from docs :

```
Log.v(TAG, "index=" + i);
```

> Don't forget that when you make a call like that when you're building the string to pass into Log.d, the compiler uses a StringBuilder and at least three allocations occur: the StringBuilder itself, the buffer, and the String object. Realistically, there is also another buffer allocation and copy, and even more pressure on the gc. That means that if your log message is filtered out, you might be doing significant work and incurring significant overhead.

Read [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Comment: So are you saying it depends on the thread it is called from?

Comment: it's going to consume some memory for sure no matter which thread we are calling from but if we choose main thread or UI thread it will impact rendering in case of large number of memory allocation for those logs while you are working on UI thread. what I was saying that logs can be called from anywhere and not restricted only to main thread.

Comment: I'm asking if you call log from a background thread if it will consume ui thread resources

Comment: it won't affect in ideal conditions.